# Android ACTION_WEB_SEARCH

Tags: java, android

I am not able to get the ACTION_WEB_SEARCH to work correctly, does this require any permissions on the AndriodManifest.xml?

This is my code:

```
 String q = edittext.getText().toString();
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH, Uri.parse(q));
 startActivity(myIntent);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Platform 2.0.

Comment: If that's the solution, don't put it in the question.  Enter it as an answer to your own question and then accept it.  This a perfectly acceptable thing to do.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
 String q = edittext.getText().toString();
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH );
 intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, q);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: how come so few web browsers support this intent?